# How to subdivide a nested list (used as a matrix) into lists based on the string in the 0th column

Tags: python, loops, nested, split

```
trees=[
['species_1', observednumber_1, calculatedvalue, calculatedvalue],
['species_2', observednumber_2, calculatedvalue, calculatedvalue],
['species_1', observednumber_3, calculatedvalue, calculatedvalue],
[etc.]
]
```

This is data from a sample site. Each row is an observation. The number of observations, the number of species involved, and the number of each species varies - i.e. there may be several individuals of each species. (I've used species_1 etc as a standin for the alphameric code for a species - there are several hundred species involved, only a few in each site - I'd like to be able to enter the code directly). The number of (observations) rows might be about 20-30 and the number of species 4-8

I need to be able to sum the calculated values for EACH of the species

The only way I see to do this is to subdivide the list into lists for each species. How can I do that? Once I've done that I can take column totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

```
import itertools as it, operator as op

# some dummy data so the example runs
observednumber_1 = 1
observednumber_2 = 2
observednumber_3 = 3
calculatedvalue = None

trees=[
  ['species_1', observednumber_1, calculatedvalue, calculatedvalue],
  ['species_2', observednumber_2, calculatedvalue, calculatedvalue],
  ['species_1', observednumber_3, calculatedvalue, calculatedvalue], ]

for k,g in it.groupby(sorted(trees,key=op.itemgetter(0)),key=op.itemgetter(0)):
  print k,sum(i[1] for i in g)
```

Result:

```
species_1 4
species_2 2
```

Notes:

- Input to `itertools.groupby` **must** be sorted by the column(s) upon which you will be grouping.
- Variables `k` and `g` stand in for "key" and "group", respectively.
- Note that `g` is a generator and if you wish to re-use it you may need to temporarily store it in a list or other data-structure.

---

Edit: I have added an example of how to use another data-structure to store the results of the generator for further calculations.

```
for k,g in it.groupby(sorted(trees,key=op.itemgetter(0)),key=op.itemgetter(0)):
  tempg = list(g)
  print k, sum(i[1] for i in tempg), sum(i[2] for i in tempg)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for one column. I apologize but my question was inadvertently ambiguous - I need the sum (in my example) of column [2] and also of column [3]. I put in dummy data and specified [2] and it comes out right, also, if I specify [3]. But if I put in both by {repeating the sum(....)} in the print statement, the second one comes out as 0's.

Comment: That's because `g` is a generator as I stated under "Notes:". You can store the results of the generator in a data-structure like a list and then do your calculations on that list instead of on the generator.

Comment: Let me know if you need me to insert an example of how to do the above.

Comment: Great, but it made me get rid of one of the key=op.itemgetter(0) in the for statement

Comment: you can do the sorting in a previous line. the code sample is succinct; not necessarily the ideal way to write code :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `defaultdict` to 'group' rows by a key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)

for row in trees:
    grouped[row[0]].append(row)
```

Now `grouped` is a dictionary with the first column as key, and the values are lists of rows that all have the same first column.

You could do the summing in-place:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(int)

for row in trees:
    grouped[row[0]] += row[1] * row[2]
```

where `row[1] * row[2]` can be any expression. Now `grouped` maps species named in the first column to the sum calculated for that species.